# Strange outputs in GitHub Branch-Deploy Action

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I am getting a weird output when running [this workflow](https://github.com/github/branch-deploy) in GitHub Actions:

```
Run github/br***nch-deploy@v5.2.2
environment: development
issueops comm***nd used with p***r***meters
✔️ PR is ***pproved ***nd ***ll CI checks p***ssed - OK
Luk***sMeine is the owner of the lock
```

As you can see, many of the characters are being replaced by a * character. My other actions in the pipeline are unaffected and running normally.

My `deploy.yaml` file looks like this:

```yaml
deploy:
    if: ${{ github.event.issue.pull_request }} # only run on pull request comments
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: test
    
    steps:
        # The branch-deploy Action
      - uses: github/branch-deploy@v5.2.2
        id: branch-deploy
        with:
          trigger: "please deploy to"
          reaction: "eyes"
          stable_branch: "main"
          prefix_only: "true"
          merge_deploy_mode: "true"
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Checkout Pull Request
        run: hub pr checkout ${{ github.event.issue.number }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Looks like you have a secret somewhere with the value `a`

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thank you so much!!